# insert selected rows(multiselect), from listbox to sheet, i want to diable those items in the listbox to avoid duplicating them in the sheet

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

```
Private Sub cmdB2_Click()
Dim i, x As Integer
 
 For i = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If Me.ListBox1.Selected(i) = True And Me.ListBox1.List(i, 1) <> "" Then
        
        Call wS_bill
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Me.ListBox1.List(i, 0)
            For x = 0 To 2
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, x) = Me.ListBox1.List(i, x)
            Me.ListBox1.List(i, x) = "" **-->error pops here**
            Me.ListBox1.Selected(i) = False
            Next x
            
        Else
        Me.ListBox1.Selected(i) = False
    End If
 Next i
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Please don't use the post title as the main description - a title plus some code without a clear description of the actual problem you're facing doesn't make for a good question. "error pops here" = *what specific error* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach, please:

```
For x = 0 To 2
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, x) = Me.ListBox1.list(i, x)
Next x
Me.ListBox1.RemoveItem (i)  'or
'Me.ListBox1.RemoveItem (Me.ListBox1.ListIndex)
```

Instead of this:

```
 For x = 0 To 2
     Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, x) = Me.ListBox1.List(i, x)
      Me.ListBox1.List(i, x) = "" '**-->error pops here**
      Me.ListBox1.Selected(i) = False
 Next x
```

The above solution cannot work for a list box linked to a range through its `RowSource`.

So, there are some issues to be also adapted. Firstly, the way of loading the list box:

1. Create a variable on top of your form module (in the declarations area, after `Option Explicit`):

   `Private arr_DispIt As Variant` 'I kept a name similar to the range name you provided...
2. In `Sub Search_R()` procedure, replace (or comment the code line):

   `Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Select`

with

```
`arr_DispIt = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Value`
```

and comment `Selection.Name = "Disp_itm"`.

We do not use the named range. We will use `arr_DispIt` instead, which will allow removing of the list box rows.

3. In `Private Sub cmdB1_Click()` replace (or comment) the line:

   `ListBox1.RowSource = "Disp_itm"`

with:

```
 `Me.ListBox1.List = arr_DispIt`
```

4. Finally use my initial proposition, but in this way:

   `Me.ListBox1.RemoveItem i: Exit For`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216596/discussion-on-answer-by-faneduru-insert-selected-rowsmultiselect-from-listbox).

Comment: i have posted a new question. "I want to use indirect formula in code"

Comment: @Sajid Mohammad: Why are you telling me that? You ware no able to confirm that the above code works or not... Why should I spend time for an issue which will never  be finalized?

Comment: @Sajid Mohammad: I posted an answer to your question, but I must confess I am not sure that I will receive some feedback. About ticking the code last side check box, in order to make it accepted answer, to help others searching for a similar issue, I lost the hope that you understood the meaning...